# Google analytics funnel wildcard

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to set up a funnel for measuring sales of products on a site.

I have steps of:

```
www.mysite.com
www.mysite.com/category
www.mysite.com/category/*
```

It's my understanding that 'www.mysite.com/category/*' will match for 'www.mysite.com/category'. But I want it to only match when they're on a product page (www.mysite.com/category/product). The product part needs to be a wildcard because it could be anything.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks for any help,
James

Comment: Can you please show what you've tried so far, including what regex expressions?

Comment: All I know how to do is 'www.mysite.com/category/*'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. ^/$
2. ^/category/?$
3. ^/category/.+

The first step is just the homepage path "/". The second step is the /category/ path only. The third step is /category/ and then any string.

Comment: This didn´t work for me, is it definitely correct syntax come 2018 ?